# Using Inheritance like this is right?

Tags: java, inheritance, uml, class-diagram, class-design

I'm student learning Inheritance in Java.

I'm making a program (Bitcoin Mining Game). In the program, there are different kind of digger (Mining Machine):

- ordinary digger (this only does digging coin),
- overclock digger (this can dig and can overclock to dig faster) and
- durability recover digger (this can dig, overclock and recover durability (every digger has durability, durability drops while digging).

I made this class diagram  (There are some attributes and methods that I didn't describe in pictures. I thought those are not needed for my question.):

[image]

I'm not sure that I did it right, in particular, the use if Inheritance.

Instead of using inheritance, should I just make a class like this? Because only one function adds to the classes:

[image]

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow!
please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a good candidate for the Decorator Pattern, which allows you to apply customized functionality to an individual object at run time. A good reference for this can be found on the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) Wikipedia page, which includes a detailed example of a Windowing system, with a UML class diagram for reference. A snippet of the code shows the decorator and the concrete decorator:

```
// abstract decorator class - note that it implements Window
abstract class WindowDecorator implements Window {
    private final Window windowToBeDecorated; // the Window being decorated

    public WindowDecorator (Window windowToBeDecorated) {
        this.windowToBeDecorated = windowToBeDecorated;
    }
    @Override
    public void draw() {
        windowToBeDecorated.draw(); //Delegation
    }
    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return windowToBeDecorated.getDescription(); //Delegation
    }
}

// The first concrete decorator which adds vertical scrollbar functionality
class VerticalScrollBarDecorator extends WindowDecorator {
    public VerticalScrollBarDecorator (Window windowToBeDecorated) {
        super(windowToBeDecorated);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        super.draw();
        drawVerticalScrollBar();
    }

    private void drawVerticalScrollBar() {
        // Draw the vertical scrollbar
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return super.getDescription() + ", including vertical scrollbars";
    }
}
```

In your case the decorator would be called `DiggerDecorator` and the concrete decorators could be called `OverclockDecorator` and `RecoverDurabilityDecorator`.

The code to instantiate a fully decorated object might look like this:

```
Digger decoratedDigger = new OverclockDecorator(new RecoverDurabilityDecorator(new SimpleDigger()));
```

As you can see, this solution still uses inheritance, but individual functionality can be "mixed in" as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didnt learn abstract class. So i am thinking im just using the first picture of diagram.

Comment: Im wondering if i use the first one is there any point that im using inheritance wrong?

Comment: And having question about decorator pattern. If i use that pattern there would be classes digger class, simple digger class. And digger decorator class , overclock digger class and durablity digger dlass. Is it right?

Comment: Digger would be an interface and the others would be classes, with DiggerDecorator being an abstract class.

Comment: To answer your question about whether you're using inheritence wrongly, it looks like a ```DurabilityRecover``` class doesn't necessarily need to be the sub-class of a ```OverclockDigger``` and this doesn't adhere to the Single Responsibility principle. In my view, this could be overcome by mixing in the functionality instead. Does this help?

Comment: You mean DurablityRecoverDigger should inherit Digger. And DurablityRecoverDigger have duplicate function(overclock)?